# /var/lib/php5 filled with empty session files

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.4

in my phpInfo i see that the session save path is /var/lib/php5 this directory gets filled with empty files with names like:

> "sess_fgf5gh2prbmnfs0ah3mcvpv4p4"

i am not using any sessions on my server. is this php default behaviour?.
this is a problem because this folder needs to gets cleaned every 30 minutes by php and should it takes too much resources.

Comment: Check in your `phpinfo()` output whether `session.autostart` is enabled.

Comment: The cause of those files existing is : using sessions.

Comment: session.autostart is off

Answer (score 0):

Facebook-sdk for PHP is making a session_start() call upon construction, which in turn made many session files that had nothing in them and needed to be cleaned up by the PHP5 cron job.
i ended up saving my session files using memcache and i stopped the cron job from executing.
this solved my cpu problem for the time being.